# Split Array value into 2nd Array inside the current array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array with the following values.

```
var keyVal = ["John, 2","Jane, 2", "John, 4","Jane, 5" ];
```

I'm trying to break out the array values into 2 it's own array so it would look like this.

```
var keyVal = [["John"][2],["Jane"][2], ["John"][2],["Jane"][2]];
```

I tried using a for loop like this:

```
for (var i=0; i< keyVal.length; i++ ){
                 keyVal[i].split(",");
             }
```

But for some reason when I go to check, nothing is changing.... What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: May I suggest a new data structure?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), the `.split` method creates a new array with strings and doesn't affect the value of the original string, so you must update the value of each item of the array:

```
for (var i=0; i< keyVal.length; i++ ){
    keyVal[i] = keyVal[i].split(",");
}
```

Comment: _"the .split method creates new String instances"_ What? You may need to clarify that a bit more.

Comment: @Cerbrus I meant that it creates a new array with strings and doesn't affect the value of the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the assignment in your loop:

```
for (var i=0; i< keyVal.length; i++ ){
    keyVal[i] = keyVal[i].split(",");
}
```

This will result in:

```
keyVal == [["John"," 2"],["Jane"," 2"],["John"," 4"],["Jane"," 5"]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Too close to the forest to see the trees I suppose.